# Export a vector layer in QGIS 3 processing script only as GPKG

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, geopackage

I'would export from a processing script (QGIS 3) a vector layer as GPKG. I'm using `self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(...))` to define the destination file. This method allows user to select the proper extension file (SHP, GPKG, ...) but I'd export the output vector of my script just in GPKG because I'm using `QgsVectorFileWriter` to create the output, which admits just one type of extension per time.
Or I'would save the `QgsVectorLayer` object that I created in the script with any extension selected by the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try to restrict accepted format in `QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination`

So, `self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(...))` could be
`self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFileDestination(..., fileFilter='GeoPackage (*.gpkg *.GPKG)'))`

The name in `fileFilter` has been deduced from list of filters from execution of `QgsVectorFileWriter.fileFilterString(QgsVectorFileWriter.VectorFormatOptions())`